# How do I append 10 arrays to form a single array in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's say I have these 10 previously declared arrays in my code.

```
  int arr1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
  int arr2[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
  int arr3[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
  int arr4[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
  int arr5[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
  int arr6[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
  int arr7[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
  int arr8[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
  int arr9[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
  int arr10[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
```

Basically, I want to append all 10 of these arrays one after another to make one single array.

```
 ArrayOfArrays = { arr1[], arr2[], arr3[], arr4[], arr5[], arr6[], arr7[], arr8[], arr9[], arr10[] }
```

How would I go about doing this? This question might seem trivial for some, but I'm new to C++ and can not figure out how to do it. Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by **add all 10 of these arrays to one single array**? like `[A]+[B]+...+[J] = [Z]` or `[Z] = [[A][B]...[J]]`

Comment: Like this: ArrayOfArrays = { arr1[], arr2[], arr3[], arr4[], arr5[], arr6[], arr7[], arr8[], arr9[], arr10[] }

Comment: So, you want to create a matrix?

Comment: Is there a constraint of using arrays? Are the sizes of all arrays pre defined/ preknown? if not then you may use linked list. otherwise if the things are pre defined then its simple to declare a resultant array n populate it

Comment: Yes the sizes are predefined. How would I declare a resultant array and populate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Basically, I want to append all 10 of these arrays one after another to make one single array.

You cannot do that.

The closest you can get to that is by using `std::array`.

```
std::array<int, 10> arr1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
...
std::array<int, 10> arr10 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

std::array<std::array<int, 10>, 10> arrayOfArray = {arr1, ..., arr10};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int arr1[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
int arr2[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
//  ...other arrays here...

// We pass a reference to a vector and return the same vector for performance reasons.
// Compiler often can optimize that into a better code.
std::vector<int> append(std::vector<int> & vec, int * data, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        vec.push_back(data[i]);
    return vec;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> data;

    data = append(data, arr1, 10);
    data = append(data, arr2, 10);

    for (auto i : data)
        std::cout << i << ", ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Also, in C++ there are good containers for storing arrays, try searching for `std::array` and `std::vector` containers. First is a fixed size static array, the other one is dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to append all 10 of these arrays one after another to make one
>   single array ?

You can have **array of pointers** like

```
int *ArrayOfPointers[10] = { &arr1, &arr2, &arr3, &arr4, &arr5, &arr6, &arr7, &arr8, &arr9, &arr10};
```

Here `ArrayOfPointers` is array of `10` int pointers i.e it can store address of `10` one dimension int array like `arr1`, `arr2` etc.

I assume there may be better method than what I'm suggesting in advance `C++` for the same task.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ it is unnecessary and ill-advised to use C-style arrays. For arrays of
constant size you may use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)
and for arrays of variable size, [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

It looks rather as if what you actually want is a constant two-dimensional matrix
and to be able to access each of its rows as as a constant array, but do not
know how to initialise a two-dimensional matrix. If that's the case, here's how:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

std::array<std::array<int,10>,10> matrix = {{
    {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}},
    {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}},
    {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}},
    {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}},
    {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}},
    {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}},
    {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}},
    {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}},
    {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}},
    {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}}
}};

int main()
{
    std::array<int,10> const & arr0 = matrix[0];
    for (int const & i : arr0) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Or more simply...
    auto const & arr5 = matrix[5];
    for (auto const & i : arr5) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Compile, link and run:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra main.cpp && ./a.out
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

[live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d360b153751985a5)